# add-to-list or push? Is there any disadvantage in using one over the other?

Tags: list, alists

I've added a line in my `early-init.el` file that sets a background color to prevent the glare during startup.

```
;; Customize background color to prevent startup glare
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(background-color . "#fff2f3"))
```

However, I've noticed that the code can also be written as:

```
;; Customize background color to prevent startup glare
(push '(background-color . "#fff2f3") default-frame-alist)
```

They both achieve the same result. I was wondering if there is any disadvantage in using one method over the other?

Comment: `add-to-list` checks by default if the element to be added exists already in the list and, if so, it does not add it again. `push` does not check. The doc string for `add-to-list` suggests that it is useful for config variables (like `default-frame-alist` above) where the uniqueness might be important, but recommends that `push` be used in Lisp code in general: `C-h f add-to-list`.

Comment: During early startup I don't think it matters then which one I use. The default-frame-alist is empty.

Comment: `push` is usually faster in such cases. Fastest: `(setq YOUR/LIST (cons NEW-ELT YOUR/LIST))`. Actually, the choice doesn't make much of a difference.  Just choose one depending on your preference.

Comment: @shynur: That's the same as push -- it expands to the same code (where appropriate).

Comment: @phils: Yes, but macro-expansion takes some time when loading `*.el`, although it's little.

Comment: I feel it's safe to say that anyone who is *concerned* about performance optimisations on that scale is not leaving their code uncompiled :)

Comment: @phils: Exactly. You think deeper than me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) makes clear what the differences are.

If you obtain the variable (its symbol) programmatically, i.e., you evaluate something to get the symbol, then use `add-to-list`. (Otherwise, with `push` you need to invoke `eval` to get the value of the resulting symbol.)

`push` adds a list element unconditionally; `add-to-list` adds an element only if not already in the list. However, you can use macro `cl-pushnew` to add an element only if not already present.

In Elisp, `push` doesn't let you provide the equivalent of `add-to-list`'s args `APPEND` and `COMPARE-FN`. However, you can use macro `cl-pushnew` to get the effect of both.

The differences generally don't matter for the use case you describe: simply adding an element to a configuration variable in your init file.  (If it matters to you whether the element is added if it's already present, then use `add-to-list` or `cl-pushnew`.)

Generally speaking `add-to-list` is more similar to `cl-pushnew` than it is to `push`.